# JUnit Classpath for InputStream

Tags: unit-testing, junit, classpath, inputstream

I have a JUnit test located within my project package in the location:

```
Java Resources > unittests > ActionTest.java
```

I am trying to use an InputStream in one of my tests that would take in a static file located in another part of my project package:

```
WebRoot > TestFiles > sampleFile.txt
```

Is there a way to go about passing the classpath of the file to the InputStream somehow? Or will I need to move the sampleFile.txt somewhere else within my project?

I have tried defining the InputStream like so:

```
InputStream fileStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sampleValidPatientList.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if WebRoot/TestFiles is in the classpath.

I generally create a /test-resources folder and put test data into it.  If I add it to the test CLASSPATH my tests can always find them.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit lost as to how to do this. If my JUnit test lies in `Project > Java Resources > unittests > ActionTest.java` then should I move my `sampleFile.txt` to `Project > Java Resources > unittests > sampleFile.txt`? It is currently in `Project > WebRoot > TestFiles > sampleFile.txt` at the moment and I'm not sure how to configure Eclipse to get the InputStream to read to that path.

Comment: Add it the test classpath.  Right click on the folder and see if there's a selection to do it.  Or, better yet, use a better IDE - IntelliJ.  I don't understand why Eclipse is so popular.